# How to find object model of an OSX application?

Tags: macos, applescript

Is there any reference documentation on the object model of every OSX application? How can I know that finder has an home attribute and textedit has a document attribute? 
Is there a way to inspect all commands and events I can use with applescript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop the application onto (Apple)Script Editor to view the dictionary.  With appscript you can also [generate HTML format documentation](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/tools.html#asdictionary).

Answer (score 0):

If you're already in AppleScript Editor, you can also select File>Open Dictionary (Cmd-Shift-O) to see a open an application's dictionary. [Script Debugger](http://www.latenightsw.com/sd4/index.html) has an additional feature where it will organize running applications near the top of a submenu for ease of selection.